# Is there a solid way of checking a c++ data-type's, size and its minimum and maximum limits

Tags: c++, types, limit, sizeof

Since size and limits of data-types of c++ could vary depending on architecture, i want to be sure their fidelity. Second code block i share below, how i check them, however it doesn't feel right. I feel like its not going to work on every system (even tho works on my computer). Is there a better way of checking a c++ data-type's byte-size and its minimum and maximum limits

these are my data-types that i use through out my projects (using stdint.h for reference)

```
#include <stdint.h>

    //more size-precise typedefs..
    typedef int8_t int8;
    #define int8_min INT8_MIN
    #define int8_max INT8_MAX
    
    typedef uint8_t uint8;
    #define uint8_min 0
    #define uint8_max UINT8_MAX
    
    typedef int16_t int16;
    #define int16_min INT16_MIN
    #define int16_max INT16_MAX
    
    typedef uint16_t uint16;
    #define uint16_min 0
    #define uint16_max UINT16_MAX
    
    typedef int32_t int32;
    #define int32_min INT32_MIN
    #define int32_max INT32_MAX
    
    typedef uint32_t uint32;
    #define uint32_min 0
    #define uint32_max UINT32_MAX
    
    typedef int64_t int64;
    #define int64_min INT64_MIN
    #define int64_max INT64_MAX
    
    typedef uint64_t uint64;
    #define uint64_min 0
    #define uint64_max UINT64_MAX
    
    //typedef size_t size;
    #define size_min 0
    #define size_max SIZE_MAX
```

and this is how i am checking their fidelities:

```
    if (!(sizeof(int8) == 1 && int8_min == -128 && int8_max == 127))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(uint8) == 1 && uint8_max == 255))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(int16) == 2 && int16_min == -32768 && int16_max == 32767))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(uint16) == 2 && uint16_max == 65535))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(int32) == 4 && int32_min == -2147483648 && int32_max == 2147483647))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(uint32) == 4 && uint32_max == 4294967295))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(int64) == 8 && int64_min == (-9223372036854775807 - 1) && int64_max == 9223372036854775807))
        //error

    if (!(sizeof(uint64) == 8 && uint64_max == 18446744073709551615))
        //error

#ifdef X64
    if (!(sizeof(size_t) == 8 && size_max == 18446744073709551615))
        //error
#elif defined(X32)
    if (!(sizeof(size_t) == 4 && size_max == 4294967295))
        //error
#else
    ? ? (i might never need this part, so dont take consideration)
#endif // X64
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to PaulMcKenzie, i've changed my code to:

```
        static_assert(sizeof(int8) == 1 && int8_min == -128 && int8_max == 127);
        static_assert(sizeof(uint8) == 1 && uint8_max == 255);
        static_assert(sizeof(int16) == 2 && int16_min == -32768 && int16_max == 32767);
        static_assert(sizeof(uint16) == 2 && uint16_max == 65535);
        static_assert(sizeof(int32) == 4 && int32_min == -2147483648 && int32_max == 2147483647);
        static_assert(sizeof(uint32) == 4 && uint32_max == 4294967295);
        static_assert(sizeof(int64) == 8 && int64_min == (-9223372036854775807 - 1) && int64_max == 9223372036854775807);
        static_assert(sizeof(uint64) == 8 && uint64_max == 18446744073709551615);
#ifdef X64
        static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == 8 && size_max == 18446744073709551615);
#elif defined(X32)
        static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == 4 && size_max == 4294967295);
#else
        static_assert(???);
#endif // X64
```

Comment: All of the fixed size types are already required to have specific range properties. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: For limits (and thus sizes) use : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits. And for C++ use the type from inlcude file <cstdint> not <stdint.h>

Comment: so i am good, i dont have to check their validations.. i guess this question was unnecessary.. i propably delete my question after couple of hours then.. thanks

Comment: guys hang on, in stdint.h, for example "uint32_t" defined as "typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;" so it is using standart data-type of c++, how is that guarantee then?

Comment: *"typedef unsigned int uint32_t;"*  That is on **your** system. It could be `unsigned long` on others, or not be present at all on a 36-bit system (has happened).

Comment: is there a solid way of checking that (for all systems) and halt (terminate) the program, or my code above is fine for that job

Comment: *is there a solid way of checking that* -- It's called [static_assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).  If the type isn't the size you require, `static_assert` will stop the compilation.  The issue with your current code is that it waits until runtime to check these things.

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(int8) == 1 && int8_min == -128 && int8_max == 127);` will stop compilation of your program if the statement isn't `true`.  In other words, you don't get to distribute your program to systems that aren't compatible, because the program could never get created in the first place.

Comment: thats been realy helpful Paul, thanks. i am not deleting but editing my question

Comment: You should post (and accept) an actual answer instead of modifying the question.

Comment: Instead of `#define` (macros... *ick ick, ptui ptui*), you could use `constexpr auto int32_max = std::numeric_limits<int32>::max();`.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of types like `uint16_t` is that they have guaranteed size and range.  You really do not need to write code to check them unless you are authoring a test suite for a C standard library implementation or something like that.

Similarly, writing code to check that `size_t` is 64 bits on a 64 bit system and 32 bits on a 32 bit system is unnecessary.

It's like testing that `int(100) == long(100)` or things like that.  Those are not the places where you program has bugs.